# Unable to access Spring Boot login error page with custom login failure handler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Whenever we try to input wrong credentials in Spring Boot login page, we got `Bad Credentials Error` with link `/login?error` I'm trying to limit a login for which I've created a custom login failure handler and whenever I try to provide wrong credentials I'm not able to get any kind of error by Spring Security at this `/login?error` page in place of this, I'm getting Status 404 Error.

**AppConfig**

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout();
}
```

**LoginFailureHandler**

```java
@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        Employee emp = service.getByUsername(username);
        if(emp!=null) {
            if (emp.isAccountNonLocked()) {
                if (emp.getFailedAttempt() < UserService.MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS - 1) {
                    service.increaseFailedAttempt(emp);
                } else {
                    service.lock(emp);
                    exception =  new LockedException("Your account has been locked due to three failed attempts"
                                +"Try again after 24 Hours....");
                }
            } else {
                if(service.unlockWhenTimeExpired(emp)){
                    exception = new LockedException("Your Account is unLocked now...." +
                                                            "try to login again");
                }
            }
        }
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");   // I'm not getting this page while a fail login
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

Since I'm unable to get this page `/login?error` I'm not able to display any message regarding failure login.

Comment: What do you get, if you enter `/login?error` in your browser manually?

Comment: @dur whitelable error page with status 404

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using spring-boot-mvc. You can overwrite the default login page by creating a `login.html` in the `src/main/resources/templates` directory.

And in it you can display your error message by utilizing `th:if="${param.error}"` like so:

```html
<div th:if="${param.error}">Wrong credentials!</div>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried and it is working with custom login page but now I've to use the spring boot mvc by default login page & but don't know why I'm getting 404 error

Comment: I have used a very similar setup myself. The only two things mine differs from yours are two additional configure steps: `.formLogin().loginPage("/login") /* this */ .defaultSuccessUrl("/") /* and this */ .failureHandler(redirectingAuthenticationFailureHandler()) /*this is basically the same as yours */ .permitAll()`

Comment: Another thing which might happen is, that you route your user to /login?error and then redirect to a different page. Check the network tab for redirects. Or better yet write some tests.

Comment: OP is using the default login page, there should not be any redirection. However, the network tab should show, which URL is not accessible.

Comment: @ValerijDobler this same AppConfig & LoginFailureHandler is working with a custom login page so why it is not working with Spring MVC login page?